# Is there a ''standard'' or commonly accepted reference for the phase of the most usual signals?

Tags: phase, norm

I am working with some very common, simple signals, such as square, triangle and sawtooth.

In my case the phase of such signals is important, so I want to be consistent throughout my work. For example, if I talk about a square signal, I want to be sure whether at $t = 0$ there is a rising edge or a falling edge.

In the literature there doesn´t seem to be any ''standard'' way of representing these signals. Sometimes symmetric triangulars are considered to begin at their lower value, sometimes at their higher, and sometimes at 0. Same happens with sawtooth.

Is there no ''standard'' or ''most correct'' phase for the most common signals?

Comment: There is not, as far as I know. But I think aiming at consistency is the right approach: define your own standard, document it, and stick to it.

Comment: You could consider standardising on the phase of the constituent sinusoid of the fundamental frequency f0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

There isn't even a standard for a sine waves signal. Two major phases are useful and they have even gotten separate signal names: sine and cosine. One is symmetric $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$ with a real spectrum and the other one is antisymmetric $\sin(-x) = \sin(x)$ with imaginary spectrum.

Both are useful properties, so you pick whatever works best for you application (and keep properly track of it). Make sure that you use the right definition when you look up the Fourier Coefficients from a table.